# How to send large GDB by E Mail or thru internet

Tags: file-geodatabase

**Is there a way to split and zip very large GDB** (over 2.5 GB) by E mail or thru internet ?.
I've tried FTP but it falls after few hours. YouSendIt (HighTalil) is only up to 250 MB for a file.

Is there a way to split and zip large GDB (over 2 GB) by E mail or thru internet ?

Comment: You should post your question on Stack Overflow as it has more to do with the size of the file you want to send than with the type of the file. Either way, emailing that large of a file should be impossible. Just ask how to send around very large files.

Comment: Why not just zip into multiple files of needed size? 7-zip or I guess any other standard archiving software will let you do that.

Comment: 2.5gb is not very large. We offsite backup and running into terrabytes via sftp without issues.

Comment: Email is extremely unlikely, as the system wasn't designed to handle that much data and is usually restricted to much smaller size limits on both ends. FTP can handle that and much larger files. With a proper client, even if a transfer fails it should be able to resume where it left off rather than starting all over again from the beginning. Most commercial file sharing sites (like YouSendIt) can handle larger files, but only with paid accounts. And as Alex mentions several archiving softwares allow for splitting files up. This question would probably be better on SuperUser rather than SO.

Comment: @BritishSteel Super User, actually. [It's one vote from closure on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925982/how-to-send-large-gdb-by-e-mail-or-thru-internet), and rightly so. SO is more programming related, SU is good for general computing issues. The close reason here was a bit misleading.

Comment: @Mapperz For future reference ^

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Dropbox account and if you have enough space left, you could place it in your Dropbox and (temporarily) make a public link that accesses your .gdb. Then simply send your link (which is unlisted) with whom you want to share your data with.